# How to link a new record (Individual) as a parent with an object (Contact), using Process Builder?

Tags: apex, process-builder, id

I need to use the process builder in order, when a Contact is modified, to create a new record (of an Individual object) ;
Then, this Individual as to be linked as a parent object to the Contact.

Is it possible with Process Builder, without coding ?
I think I'll need the ids of the new records,

I did the trailhead on the subject but never used it on a real case, that's why every advice will be listened to :)

Thanks

EDIT :
My need is ->
when a contact is modified, if there is no Individual linked to the contact, create one ;
The Individual has to become the parent of the contact, and inherit some attributes from the Contact (lastname..)

I'm locked after creating the condition, at the creation of the Individual object :
I need to link the Individual to the account and create the relation (lookup I think ?)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! As written, we don't have enough information to help you. Please read more about [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/226098/edit) your question to include additional details. Details like any error messages, framework error messages, etc would be useful, as well as the code you've written so far.

Comment: (Just edited my post)

Comment: @AlexisMASSON You could create a Checkbox(as a Flag) on the Contact and use it to flag with no individual. And have a Process flow so that it checks for the flag whenever a contact is modified. So based on this, you could get all the necessary fields from the existing contact and have them on the Individual(I am not sure if this a custom object or whatever).

Comment: What is an "Individual"? Is that a "User" or a custom object named "Individual"? A screen capture of your schema (from schema explorer with just the relevant objects) would be very helpful here.

Comment: Hi, Individual is a new SF object, it seems that it's been added for the new regulation (GDPR) ; I heared about it two days ago -> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_individual.htm

Answer (score 2):

Process Builder alone is probably not capable of handling this, but in combination with a Flow, it can be done without code.

Study up on Flows first, then build a flow that is launched by Process Builder whenever a Contact is edited.

In the Flow, the first step is a "Fast Lookup" on the "Individual__c" object to find any Individual records that are a parent of the Contact. 
Then a decision element to test if an Individual record was found or not.  If not, a Record Create element can create the Element, and finally a Record Update to update the Contact's lookup field (lookup to Individual).

Comment: Ok, I'm trailheading about flows, process builder etc,
Thanks for the idea, I hope I'll be able to do it soon